# Proving complex conjugation

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

$f : C → C$ is an isometry such that $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 1$ and $f(i) = −i$. Prove that $f(z) = \bar z$ for all $z ∈ C$

I am having trouble figuring out where to go with this.

I thought that since this is an isometry, if I take some $x,y \in C$ then take their distance $D(x,y)$ and then under $D(f(x), f(y)) = D(\bar x, \bar y)$, it should be that $D(x,y)= D(\bar x, \bar y)$.

I can clearly see that if $ z = a+bi$ where $a,b  \in R$ then:

$a+bi = 0$ implies $a = 0, b=0$ and $\bar z = 0 - 0i$

$a+bi = 1$ implies $a = 1, b=0$ and $\bar z = 1 - 0i$

$a+bi = i$ implies $a = 0, b=1$ and $\bar z = 0 - 1i$

So this the proposition is true for $z = 0, 1, i$. I don't know how to show this is true for all $ z ∈ C$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: More generally , if  $f : E\to E$ and $g : E\to E$ are isometries of the Euclidean plane, and if $f,g$ agree on $3$ non-collinear points ,then $f=g$. We can take $C$ as a model for $E$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$|f(z)|^2=|z|^2$ means 
$$f(z) \overline{f(z)}=z \bar{z}$$

$|f(z) - 1|^2 = |z - 1|^2$ means
$$f(z) \overline{f(z)}-f(z)- \overline{f(z)}+1 =z \bar{z}-z-\bar{z} +1$$

$|f(z) + i|^2 = |z - i|^2$ means 
$$f(z) \overline{f(z)}-if(z)+i\overline{f(z)}+1 =z \bar{z}+iz-i\bar{z} +1$$

Now plug the first relation into the other two, and you are done.

Comment: I used what you said as a system of equations and got the answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Plugging the three known identities ($f(0), f(1), f(i)$) into the distance function $|f(z) - f(z')| = |z - z'|$ yields:
$$ |f(z)| = |z|, |f(z) - f(1)| = |z - 1|, |f(z) - f(i)| = |z + i|$$
Since the distance from a point $f(z)$ to $0, 1, i$ are fixed, geometrically three circles centred at $0, 1, i$ must have at most one intersection $f(z)$. Therefore the function $f = \overline{z}$.

Comment: That first part makes sense to me but how does them having a single intersection point imply that $ f= \bar z$ ?

Comment: @Nid The value of $f(z)$ wholly depends on its distance to $0, 1$ and $i$.